# Embed Avatar JS in Java Application Example

Tags: java, node.js, nashorn, avatarjs

Using Java 8, I'd like to programmatically load a javascript file and execute it using [Avatar JS](https://avatar-js.java.net/) (for Node env support). I also want to use Maven to manage the dependencies.

Here's the simple Nashorn snippet I'm using and I'd like to extend this to support Node.JS modules, ideally using Avatar JS.

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("js/hello-world.js");
String result = (String)engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(in));
System.out.print(result);
```

The relevant Maven config also looks like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>avatar-js</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.32-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>libavatar-js-linux-x64</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.32-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I get the impression there's a lot of good functionality in Avatar, but I'm struggling to find any decent docs or examples. Can anyone provide a code example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, the relevant code I have running looks like this:

```
import com.oracle.avatar.js.Server;
import com.oracle.avatar.js.Loader;
import com.oracle.avatar.js.log.Logging;
```

and

```
String runJs() throws Throwable {

    StringWriter scriptWriter = new StringWriter();
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    ScriptContext scriptContext = engine.getContext();
    scriptContext.setWriter(scriptWriter);
    Server server = new Server(engine, new Loader.Core(), new Logging(false), System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    server.run("js/hello-world.js");

    return scriptWriter.toString();
}
```

and, for now, a simple `hello-world.js`:

```
var util = require('util')
var result = util.format('hello %s', 'Phil');
print(result);
```

I also pass in `java.library.home` as a JVM argument when running the application. The Avatar native library resides in this directory